# JWT Invalid Signature on Linux Container .Net Core 2.2

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, openshift, jwt

I have been working on implementing JWT bearer based authentication. I am trying to fetch public keys from Auth server JWKS URL and load it to JsonWebKeySet. Here is my ConfigureServices class code:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(o=> { o.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin", b=> b.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()); });
        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(o => { o.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowAnyOrigin")); });
        var p = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
        services.AddMvc(o=> {
            o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(p));
        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        // configure strongly typed settings objects
        var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

        // configure jwt authentication
        var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
        //var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);

        //Call Auth service URL to get public keys
        var jwksJson = Helpers.GetKeyAsync(appSettings.jwksURL).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        //load keys from JWKS
        var jwks = new JsonWebKeySet(jwksJson);

        var issuerSigningKeys = jwks.Keys.ToList();

        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKeys = issuerSigningKeys,
                //IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });

        // configure DI for application services
        services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
    }
```

And here is my Configure method

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

This code works perfectly fine when I run the API on my local machine (IIS Express) with my angular front-end and Postman. However, when I deploy this code to Openshift based Linux container I always receive 401 error saying "The Signature is invalid". I am using the same token for authentication on both local and Openshift container. Wondering if Linux based container is causing the problem.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am struggling with the same issue: token validation works fine locally (Windows, Kestrel) but on CentOS and Ubuntu (also Kestrel) it says the signature is invalid. Any help appreciated!